# JQuery plugin slick with Flexbox

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox, slick.js

Is slick incompatible with flexbox displays? If my `div` container is set to `display: flex` all of the slides are displayed as a continuous line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a container to `display: flex`, by default it sets the [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) to `row` (i.e., *all of the slides are displayed as a continuous line*).

You can switch to a vertical alignment by adding `flex-direction: column` to the container.

You can also nest flexboxes, enabling you to align some elements in a row, and others in a column.

Comment: Fantastic, that got rid of the slides showing in a row but now when the page initially loads two slides are squeezed into the container even though I have set `slidesToShow: 1`. Scrolling resets the carousel back to showing only one slide.

Comment: You may want to post code or a demo in your question. But based on what you're saying, seems like you're dealing with another flexbox default. The [`flex-wrap`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/) property is by default `nowrap`, meaning flex items (child elements) won't wrap. Try adding `flex-wrap: wrap` to the container (although this may not be an issue if you're in `column` alignment). Also try applying `width: 100%` or [`flex-basis: 100%`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-basis/) to each flex item.

Comment: Sadly, your suggestions didn't work. I'll post it as a separate problem.

Comment: It's generally better if you post enough code in your question so the problem can be reproduced. A live demo is also useful. If you can do that let me know. I'll take a closer look.